# no database selected c# MySqlDatabase

Tags: c#, mysql

I have used this connection to my program several times, but this time when i run the program it keeps saying "no database selected".

I need the code to Count rows in MySqlDatabase table "aktiviteter" and add 1 to that number and insert it to my textbox "idAk_txt"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public OpretAktivitet()
        {
           HentAntal();
        }
 private void HentAntal()
        {
            string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=*********";
            string Query = "select count(*) as antal from aktiviteter";
            MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDatabase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            try
            {
                conDatabase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {


                    int antal = Convert.ToInt32(myReader.GetString("antal").ToString()); ;

                    antal += 1;

                    idAk_txt.Text = Convert.ToString(antal);


                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"datasource=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog='yourDBname';username=root;password=*********";
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** you have not given `Database` name in `ConnectionString`

**Solution :**  you should provide your `databasename` in your connection string

Try This:

```
string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;database=databasename;username=root;password=*********";
```

Comment: @Max: you are welcome :) I'm glad to be help of you.